# Image type as background in drupal-7

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, content-type

Hi everybody: i had define a new content type that have:
a title, a link field, and a image field. 
So, i want to make that image comes to be the background of the content type when i show it. How can i do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean the background of the whole page or just the node content area?

Comment: No, i want the image that i have upload(in the image-field) become to be the background of that content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very quick way to do this would be to add a custom `node.tpl.php` to your theme and do this:

```
<?php
$url = file_create_url($node->field_image[$node->language][0]['uri']);
?>
<div style="background:url(<?php echo $url; ?>) left top no-repeat;" id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
// Rest of node.tpl.php here
```

Comment: Mmmm i was googling and i've found a background field, but i don't have any idea how to use it. Your solution is valid too. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to comment on Clive's answer, but do not have the "rep" :(. Wouldn't it be best with a check for node-type?

```
<?php
if ($type == 'MACHINE_NAME_FOR_YOUR_TYPE') {
    $url = file_create_url($node->field_image[$node->language][0]['uri']);
?>
<div style="background:url(<?php echo $url; ?>) left top no-repeat;" id="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
<?php } ?>
```

// Rest of node.tpl.php here

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) module, check [Field Group Background Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group_background_image).

Steps:

1. Go to the *Manage Display* page of your content type
2. Create a `div (background image)` field group as a wrapper of the node
3. Select the image field you want to use. Optionally, you can specify an image style
4. Do not output your image field